# Iterate over files in bash, in Jenkins pipeline, fails with MissingPropertyException

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Pipeline job in Jenkins and there is a step that executes this bash script:

```
sh """
      $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb pull /sdcard/Pictures/screenshots
      if [ "$DEFAULT_LOCALE" = "en" ]
      then
          DEFAULT_LOCALE="en-US"
      fi

      if [ "${env.UPDATE_BASE}" == "true" ] || [ ! -d "${env.CACHE_HOME}/${env.BRANCH}" ]; then
        if [ ! -d "${env.CACHE_HOME}/${env.BRANCH}" ]; then
          mkdir -p ${env.CACHE_HOME}/${env.BRANCH}
        fi
        for imgfile in screenshots/*.png; do
          if [[ $imgfile == *"_${env.DEFAULT_LOCALE}-"*.png ]]; then
            cp -rf screenshots/$imgfile ${env.CACHE_HOME}/${env.BRANCH}
          fi
        done
      else
        rm -f screenshots/*_${env.DEFAULT_LOCALE}-*.png
        cp -rf ${env.CACHE_HOME}/${env.BRANCH}/* screenshots
      fi
    """
```

However, when the pipeline reaches this step, it fails with this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: imgfile for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

What is wrong in the script?

Comment: Don't you need `sh -c`  or rather `bash -c` ?

Comment: `sh` does not accept `[[` unless your system is configured with `sh` symlinked to the `bash` shell. Better run with `bash`

Comment: Either way you should use the same style of square brackets consistently. You're using both.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Apparently `sh` is a Jenkins command and `-c` isn't required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your variables are shell variables then you should use triple single quotes.

If you have a mix of shell and Groovy variables (or only Groovy ones) then you should use triple double quotes.

In order to defer the evaluation of the shell variables in the latter case, you need to escape their dollar signs using one of these forms (I'm not sure which):

```
if [[ \$imgfile == *"_${env.DEFAULT_LOCALE}-"*.png ]]; then
```

or

```
if [[ \\$imgfile == *"_${env.DEFAULT_LOCALE}-"*.png ]]; then
```

or

```
if [[ ${'$'}imgfile == *"_${env.DEFAULT_LOCALE}-"*.png ]]; then
```